# onPause(): SuperNotCalledException even if super.onPause() is there

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onpause

I'm trying to test SharedPreferences by using the code in  [developer.android.com SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). I tried to change it slightly since they say onStop ["may never be called"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29). The problem is that onPause gives me this weird error even if the first line of the override is a super.onPause().

```
03-09 14:41:00.883: E/AndroidRuntime(394): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.mobinoob.saveinfo/com.mobinoob.saveinfo.SaveInfoActivity} did not call through to super.onPause()
```

Here is an example of the code:

```
public class SaveInfoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListener();
    loadText();
    textSaved = "";
    created = true;
}

private boolean created = false;

private void addListener() {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textSaved = s.toString();
            System.out.println("text:" + textSaved);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    });

}

private static String fileName = "savedInfo.txt";
private static String propertyName = "text";
private String textSaved;

@Override 
protected void onPause() {}{
     super.onPause();
     if (created) {
         saveText();
     }
}
private void loadText() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings == null)
        return;
    String result = settings.getString(propertyName, "");
    setText(result);
}

private void saveText() {
    System.out.println("saving");
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(propertyName, textSaved);
    editor.commit();

}
private void setText(String result) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(result);
    System.out.println("restore" + result);
}
```

Any idea where I'm missing something? Also note the if(created) that is needed because onPause() is also called the first time I start the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected void onPause() {}{
```

You've got an extra pair of curly braces in there, making it look like an empty function.

Comment: 10 minutes to register and post the question and what? 10second to spot a silly typo.:) I read it several times and didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo to me...notice the empty braces right after onPause().  That is likely being detected as your method.

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() {}{
     super.onPause();
     if (created) {
         saveText();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ( I suppose that's the power of more eyes checking the code.) Also it's strange that Eclipse doesn't warn me.

Comment: It can't warn that you had an empty function when you shouldn't have, of course... but I am surprised it didn't complain about an anonymous function in the middle of nowhere!

Comment: I checked again. No warning at all.